# Escape/sanitize user input in Clojure/Compojure

Tags: clojure, xss, compojure

I am using Clojure/Ring/Compojure-0.4/Enlive stack to build a web application.

Are there functions in this stack that would either strip HTML or HTML-encode (i.e. `<a>` to `&lt;a&gt;`) user-supplied strings in order to prevent XSS attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out Enlive *does* escape HTML by default if you use `net.cgrand.enlive-html/content` to put text into a HTML element.

```
(sniptest "<p class=\"c\"></p>" [:.c] (content "<script></script>"))
"<p class=\"c\">&lt;script&gt;&lt;/script&gt;</p>"
```

Answer (score 19):

`hiccup.util/escape-html` in [hiccup](http://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) does it.  That function used to be in Compojure itself (since all of the functionality in hiccup used to be part of Compojure).  It's a simple enough function that you could easily write it yourself though.

```
(defn escape-html
  "Change special characters into HTML character entities."
  [text]
  (.. #^String (as-str text)
    (replace "&" "&amp;")
    (replace "<" "&lt;")
    (replace ">" "&gt;")
    (replace "\"" "&quot;")))
```

There's also `clojure.contrib.string/escape`, which takes a map of char -> string escape sequences and a string and escapes it for you.

```
user> (clojure.contrib.string/escape {\< "&lt;" \> "&gt;"} "<div>foo</div>")
"&lt;div&gt;foo&lt;/div&gt;"
```

This strikes me as not as useful as it could be, because you might want to escape multi-character sequences and this won't let you.  But it might work for your HTML-escaping needs.

And then there are many Java libraries for this, of course.  You could use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) from Apache Commons:

```
(org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils/escapeHtml4 some-string)
```

This strikes me as a bit heavyweight for this purpose though.

Comment: The correct URL to StringEscapeUtils http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html

Comment: Updated url http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 15):

*Update: I knew there had to be more than that...*

`ring.util.codec` from `ring-core` has a functions called which work like so:

```
user> (require '[ring.util.codec :as c])
nil
user> (c/url-encode "<a>")
"%3Ca%3E"
user> (c/url-decode "<a>")
"<a>"
```

These are wrappers around `java.net.URLEncoder` and `java.net.URLDecoder`. The same namespace provides functions for dealing with Base64 encoding, based on a class from Apache Commons.

---

*Original answer follows.*

I'm not sure whether there is a public function to do this, but `Enlive` has two private functions called `xml-str` and `attr-str` which do this:

```
(defn- xml-str
 "Like clojure.core/str but escapes < > and &."
 [x]
  (-> x str (.replace "&" "&amp;") (.replace "<" "&lt;") (.replace ">" "&gt;")))
```

(`attr-str` also escapes `"`.)

You could get at that function with `@#'net.cgrand.enlive-html/xml-str` (Clojure doesn't tend to make things *really* private...) or just copy it to your own namespace.

Comment: That's a bit of a bummer. Sounds like a major oversight in most Clojure web frameworks.

Comment: Apparently the situation isn't quite so bad: see the updated answer. :-)

Comment: Looks like I was a little hasty to blame Enlive, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: URL encoding really isn't the same as HTML-encoding.
url-encode("<a>") => "%3Ca%3E" where as html-encode("<a>") => "&lt;a&gt;"

Comment: Siddhartha Reddy: Right. I seem to have forgotten the spec between posting the original answer and making the edit -- thanks for pointing it out. At least both options do make user input safe. *(sigh)* Anyway, `xml-str` does use `&foo;` entities; too bad it's private. And of course Brian's answer is really the best fit to the question as stated above.